# User-defined Java class import problem using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to translate a fairly large C/C++ application to Java. First step is to translate C/C++ structs and classes to Java classes. I am new to Java and Eclipse and immediately hit a problem. The source code below shows this. The importing class could not 'see' the user-defined package name and the user-defined imported class name. 
Source code:

File Pers.java that contains the user-defined class Pers and is created by New Project + New class

```
package perspack;
public class Pers {
    String name;
    String surname;
    public Pers(String name, String surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    }
public String getName() {
    return name;
    }
public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
    }
}
```

File Perstest.java imports the user-defined Pers class and is created by New Project + New class:

```
package perstestpack;
import perspack.Pers;

public class Perstest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pers justtoseeifitworks = new Pers; 
        System.out.println("Hallo Person");
    }
}
```

perspack in import perspack.Pers gives error: 'The import perspack cannot be resolved'.
The 'Pers' class references in main method give error: 'Pers cannot be resolved to a type'.

What do I need to do in Eclipse to make this work? (I thought Eclipse would do it...)

I am using Eclipse Java 2018-12 on a Windows 10 desktop.

I also tried the same input files on NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 and got similar errors.

Comment: Most likely `classpath` issue.

Comment: both are in same package. there is no need of the import statement. Try by removing the import.

Comment: They're not in the same package.

Comment: You said that you ran "New Project + New class" twice. Are you sayng that you created each file in a _separate project_? Because if so, then that's not what you should be doing.

Comment: You should put them in the same project. (Otherwise you need a dependency manager to make sure the compiler and eventually the runtime can find all stuff.)

Answer (score 0):

Open the test project's Properties dialog, and on the Java Build Path page, navigate over to the Projects tab. Make sure the project containing the `Pers` class is present and selected there.

https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm?cp=1_4_5_1